# NetworkInterface.Id Property Alternaive in C WINAPI

Tags: c#, c, winapi

I'm trying to get each adapter's identifier in C WINAPI but I couldn't find it. However in C#, there is a NetworkInterface.Id Property can do the trick.

```
foreach (var adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (adapter.Id == "4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318")
    {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

What should I do in C, or just I can't achieve it?

Comment: The source is here : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/net/NetworkInformation/SystemNetworkInterface.cs  you want to use this winapi :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses with this struct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh id is AdapterName field

Comment: [GetInterfaceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getinterfaceinfo) returns an [IP_INTERFACE_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ipexport/ns-ipexport-ip_interface_info) that holds individual [IP_ADAPTER_INDEX_MAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ipexport/ns-ipexport-ip_adapter_index_map) entries. The `Name` field is presumably, what you're after.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. AdapterName is exactly what I'm looking for. No idea why windows have such strange naming style.